# LabVIEW WebService

Tags: web-services, labview

I have seen on all the subject you talking about labview many times. 
First I am a French student so please excuse me for my English.

I have to read some data on a broadcast computer and publish it on internet with the function WebService of LabVIEW. My teacher told me to create a WWW client which can read the data in the aim to separate it and publish only what I need.

I have any idea of how can I do that so I would like to know if you can give me some help to begin.
I hope you can understand what I wanted to say.

Best regards,
Baccadr

Answer (score 4):

Without more details, it's hard to know exactly what you're doing.  It sounds like you are:

1. Reading data from a "broadcast computer"... possibly from the web or internet.
2. Filtering the data that you read for a specific set of data
3. Publishing the data through a web service.

So...

1. You can use the [TCP communication functions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/lvcomm/tcp_vi_descriptions/) for basic open/write request/read response from a web server.  Or, the [UDP functions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/lvcomm/udp_vi_descriptions/), if you have a UDP broadcast.
2. The data that you read is likely to be a string, and should be possible to filter with the [string functions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/TOC111.htm).
3. There's a tutorial on setting up LabVIEW web services [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/lvhowto/build_web_service/).

My apologies, there seem to be very few current resources in French.  Good luck!